# Status:404 cannot get/ heroku. Monogodb connected successfully

Tags: mongodb, heroku, http-status-code-404

I’ve been trying to get my app to deploy to Heroku for hours, but I’m getting a 404 Cannot Get/ error on my screen. Everything works locally too.

I’ve added a start code to my script in my packaging.json file, I’ve pushed everything through git, monogodb atlas is connected successfully and pulling information locally. I think it’s something on the front end side but I cannot figure out what it could be!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70637641/404-not-found-when-requesting-after-deploying-to-heroku-works-locally.  also check the heroku log.